# How do I access the container within reopenClass, without touching globals?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

Currently building an Ember.js app using ember-cli.

Within a `reopenClass` for a model, I need to use the Ember Data "store":

```
Business.reopenClass({

  search: function(params) {
    # nope, there is no "store" on the class/static object
    var store = this.store;
  }

});
```

I know that I can use a global, but **globals are so dirty**:

```
Business.reopenClass({

  search: function(params) {
    # this works, but the `window` global & `__container__` accessor are verbotten
    var store = window.App.__container__.lookup("store:main");
  }

});
```

How does one use `lookup` or `lookupFactory` from within a class/static function?

Comment: you don't, the classes aren't bound to their namespace.  The better question is what is business(aside from the described "model"), and why do you want the store on it, maybe you should use an injector to add the store to it?

Comment: I'm defining a #search function on a model's class, attempting to reuse as much of Ember Data's internals as possible to make custom AJAX call and extract the result.

Comment: search seems like it would more appropriately belong on a route or controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution; following Ember's guard rails:

My Business#search method performs custom AJAX using RESTAdapter#ajax. Appropriately moved out to the adapter, where Container#lookup is possible.

```
var BusinessAdapter = ApplicationAdapter.extend({

  search: function(params) {
    // first class access to the container
    var store = this.container.lookup("store:main");
    // ...
    var promise = this.ajax(url, "GET", { data: params }).then(function(adapterPayload) {
      // ...
    });
    return promise;
  }

});
```